# Is there anything in integral calculus other than definite and indefinite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Calculus is a branch of mathematics that deals with the rate of change of functions with respect to the input. Integral calculus is an important part of Calculus. According to the textbook, I am following, integral calculus is mainly is of two types: Indefinite integral and the definite integral. Indefinite integral deals with the calculation of actual function whenever its derivative is given. Definite integral deals with the area bounded by the graph of the function.

Is there anything in integral calculus other than definite and indefinite integrals?

Comment: That area definition is quite dangerous. Is area can be negative? I think that in some cases, definite integrals are kind of connection between function values on given domain. Stokes/Green  thms are great examples.

Comment: Yes, their usefulness in a myriad of situations, such as finding areas, volumes and many other geometric concepts. Statistics which wouldn't exist without using the integral. Open a physics textbook. It's filled with integrals or differential equations which are solved using the integral.

Comment: I don't think the OP is asking if integrals are useful, or for applications of definite integrals. The question seems to be asking "Is there another kind of integral, besides a ***definite*** integral and an ***indefinite*** integral". I know there are many concepts in integral calculus, Riemann/Lebesgue/Daniell/etc. integrals, line/contour/surface/volume/etc. integrals, but it seems to me like they always either do/do not have a domain of integration, so that they are either definite or indefinite. But I'm interested to see if someone more knowledgeable has any examples of something else.

Comment: Is there anything else?  Double integrals, line integrals, surface integrals, Stieltjes integrals, Lebesgue integrals, ... we could go on.